# How does intelligent code completion work in Scheme?

Tags: emacs, scheme, code-intelligence

From reading a Lisp book I remember they showed an example of an OOP-style method dispatcher based on closures:

```
(defun create-object ()
  (let ((val 0)
        (get (lambda () val))
        (set (lambda (new-val) (setq val new-val)))
        (inc (lambda () (setq val (+ 1 val)))))
    (lambda (method)
      (cond ((eq method 'get)
             get)
            ((eq method 'set)
             set)
            ((eq method 'inc)
             inc)))))

(let ((obj (create-object)))
  (funcall (obj 'set) 1)
  (funcall (obj 'inc))
  (funcall (obj 'get))) ;; 2
```

Since it's just a function with a <s>string</s> symbol argument, I guess code intel won't be of much help here, not completing the method names or their signatures. (Compare with a similar JavaScript object.)

Is this problem generally solved? How do you program an object system in Scheme so that an editor (like Emacs) can be more intelligent with your code?

P.S. The example may be not a valid Scheme code, but you should get the idea.

Comment: you could have a special function like in python `__dir__` which will return all the possible keys that can be used on the object.

Comment: Just because OOP _can_ be implemented that way doesn't mean that it usually _is_.  But even here, using `eq` on strings typically isn't a good idea, so it'd be more common to compare symbols (e.g., `(eq method 'get)`) and doing completion based on the symbols that the reader has seen is straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made some starting code for you.
It's for Emacs Lisp, but it's should be very easily portable to Scheme.

Here's your usage example:

```
(defun create-object ()
  (lexical-let* ((val 0)
                 (get (lambda() val))
                 (set (lambda(x) (setq val x))))
    (generate-dispatch-table get set)))

(setq obj (create-object))
(funcall (funcall obj 'get))
;; => 0
(funcall (funcall obj 'set) 1)
;; => 1
(funcall (funcall obj 'get))
;; => 1
(scheme-completions obj)
;; => (get set)
```

And here's how it's implemented:

```
(defmacro generate-dispatch-table (&rest members)
  `(lambda (method)
     (cond ,@(mapcar
               (lambda (x) `((eq method ',x) ,x)) members))))

(defun collect (pred x)
  (when (and x (listp x))
    (let ((y (funcall pred x))
          (z (append
              (collect pred (car x))
              (collect pred (cdr x)))))
      (if y
          (append (list y) z)
        z)))) 

(defun scheme-completions (obj)
  (collect
   (lambda(x) (and (eq (car x) 'eq)
              (eq (cadr x) 'method)
              (eq (caaddr x) 'quote)
              (cadr (caddr x))))
   obj))
```

And here's a simple visual interface for completions:

```
(require 'helm)
(defun scheme-completions-helm ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((y (and
               (looking-back "(funcall \\([^ ]*\\) +")
               (intern-soft (match-string 1)))))
    (when y
      (helm :sources
            `((name . "members")
              (candidates . ,(scheme-completions (eval y)))
              (action . (lambda(x) (insert "'" x))))))))
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it gives a concrete example of how an object system can make an editor aware of the system. If I may summarize, 1) an object should have a distinct signature for accessing members and 2) an interface to list *all* its members.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a Emacs user, but use DrRacket and it does have an object system and do what an IDE should do, but I know Emacs is very customizable since it uses `elisp` so you can make support for your own syntax both in syntax highlighting and tab-completion. So you do:

1. Make your own object system
2. Edit your Emacs editor to do what you want

Many of my colleagues use it and they fix their Emacs in such ways.

Another thing, this question makes me think about the [resources at schemewiki.org on the subject](http://community.schemewiki.org/?object-oriented-programming) where the different approaches are mentioned and even a similar code to the one you posted is posted as example. It's a good read.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's interesting indeed! Particularly the page about advanced object systems.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid double notion of symbols in `create-object` via an `obarray`.
Furthermore, the interface of the object are all functions. Therefore, use `fset` and avoid the double `funcall`.

```
(defun create-object ()
  (lexical-let (val
        (_oa (make-vector 11 0)))
    (fset (intern "get" _oa) (lambda () val))
    (fset (intern "inc" _oa) (lambda () (incf val)))
    (fset (intern "set" _oa) (lambda (new-val) (setq val new-val)))
    (lambda (method &rest args)
      (apply 'funcall (intern (symbol-name method) _oa) args))))


(fset 'obj1 (create-object))
(fset 'obj2 (create-object))

(obj1 'set 1)
(obj2 'set 2)

(obj1 'inc)
(obj2 'inc)
(obj2 'inc)

(obj2 'get)
(obj1 'get)
```

Example for inheritance:

```
(defun create-object ()
  (lexical-let (val
        (_oa (make-vector 11 0)))
    (fset (intern "get" _oa) (lambda () val))
    (fset (intern "inc" _oa) (lambda () (incf val)))
    (fset (intern "set" _oa) (lambda (new-val) (setq val new-val)))
    (lambda (method &rest args)
      (apply 'funcall (or (intern-soft (symbol-name method) _oa)
              (error "Undefined function: %s" method))
         args))))


(defun create-object-add10 ()
  (lexical-let ((base (create-object))
        (_oa (make-vector 11 0)))
    (fset (intern "inc" _oa) (lambda () (funcall base 'set (+ (funcall base 'get) 10))))
    (lambda (method &rest args)
      (let ((call (intern-soft (symbol-name method) _oa)))
    (if call
        (apply 'funcall call args)
      (apply 'funcall base method args))))))

(fset 'obj1 (create-object))
(fset 'obj2 (create-object-add10))

(obj1 'set 1)
(obj2 'set 2)

(obj1 'inc)
(obj2 'inc)
(obj2 'inc)

(obj2 'get)
(obj1 'get)
```

The definition of `create-object`-like methods should additionally be supported through macros. That is not done here.

For more features, note, there is a CLOS-compatible object oriented system in emacs:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eieio/index.html

Comment: Thanks, that's nice! I can see how an obarray may be likened to a JavaScript object and make completion function (like in @abo-abo's answer) easier to write.

Comment: Yes and the obarray changes the linear time access to constant time access. It gets close to the internal look-up method. This may matter for large objects.

Comment: I think closures are not the best way to implement objects. Lists of obarrays are better since they allow inheritance.

Comment: You mean, the data obarray (`val` in the example) should be in the same list as the methods obarray?

Comment: I have to apologize. I thought of representing classes as lists of obarrays. But, that turned out to be cumbersome because `copy-tree` and `copy-sequence` do not copy the vectors so the objects would share the data which is just wrong or one would have to write one's own copy. As a compensation I added an example for inheritance with the old concept. The `inc`-function is overwritten in the derived class created with `create-object-add10`. Actually, I did not really want to write that code because one has many examples in the link from Sylwester's answer.